# Creating GIF animation from multiple JPG images using GPU

Tags: linux, gpu, gif

Is there any way to create a GIF animation out of 50 or more JPG files ( pretty big files ) using the GPU ?

At this moment it takes about 15 secs to create a GIF out of 24 JPG images and looking for a much faster solution ( using ImageMagick ).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you knnow Lempel–Ziv–Welch encoding algorithm? Maybe it is used to encode images inside.

Answer (score 0):

Not really what you are asking for, but you could try using gifsicle instead of imagemagick. It should create gifs faster.